# Issues with Pushbullet Pro Account

Tags: pushbullet

I am facing issues with my pushbullet account on desktop. Im on a Pro subscription but its not showing on my account and all my devices are not showing. Not able to send out any batch SMS as well via excel macro.

Once logged in using gmail, my icon still shows Pro (badge with star).
but after test sending 1 SMS, the SMS gets stuck and unable to send out, and after that my icon changes to black in colour without the badge+star and all my devices can not be seen.
Sometimes the ratelimitX appears but i am not running any pushes at all.
Have already cleared push history but problem still persist.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming problem. It might be on topic for https://superuser.com/ but it really sounds like a job for pushbullet's customer support.